# When to include normal component of acceleration in total accerleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

So according to the answer the acceleration of the bucket is only the tangential acceleration component.

I was wondering why for this specific problem normal component of acceleration was taken in to consideration because isn't

accerleation = acc_normal + acc_tangential.

In this problem it seems that only acc_tangential was taken in to account for the total acceleration. Can someone explain why this is the case

Answer shown below:

[image]

Comment: Parts of the rope are going in a circle (and therefore have a centripetal acceleration. Is the *bucket* going in a circle?

Comment: I thought so as well just wanted to confirm thank you so much!

Comment: The bucket doesn't accelerate sideways. Only downwards. Which is tangential to the circle.